# Problem converting xsi:nil="true" to NUll by OpenXML

Tags: xml, null, sql-openxml

I am sending data from a C# Windows forms application as XML to SQL
The problem is that NULL values ​​are converted and sent as xsi:nil="true".
And when read by OpenXML it encounters an error
Thank you all

**Sample Query :**

```
DECLARE @TimeConvert XML
    = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TimeConvertCreateVm>
    <Characters>02</Characters>
    <TimeLeaveId>ec7c864b-7ebc-4d58-a94d-eb923fd20663</TimeLeaveId>
    <TimeMissionId xsi:nil="true" />
  </TimeConvertCreateVm>
  <TimeConvertCreateVm>
    <Characters>05</Characters>
    <TimeLeaveId xsi:nil="true" />
    <TimeMissionId>f03bb792-5a17-4467-b097-0bd819884fc1</TimeMissionId>
  </TimeConvertCreateVm>
</ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm>';

DECLARE @handler INT;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handler OUT, @TimeConvert;

SELECT Characters,   -- Characters - nvarchar(max)
       TimeLeaveId,  -- TimeLeaveId - uniqueidentifier
       TimeMissionId -- TimeMissionId - uniqueidentifier
FROM
    OPENXML(@handler, 'ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm/TimeConvertCreateVm')
    WITH
    (
        [Characters] NVARCHAR(50) 'Characters',
        [TimeLeaveId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 'TimeLeaveId',
        [TimeMissionId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 'TimeMissionId'
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.
Also, `OPENXML()` cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @TimeConvert XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TimeConvertCreateVm>
        <Characters>02</Characters>
        <TimeLeaveId>ec7c864b-7ebc-4d58-a94d-eb923fd20663</TimeLeaveId>
        <TimeMissionId xsi:nil="true"/>
    </TimeConvertCreateVm>
    <TimeConvertCreateVm>
        <Characters>05</Characters>
        <TimeLeaveId xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TimeMissionId>f03bb792-5a17-4467-b097-0bd819884fc1</TimeMissionId>
    </TimeConvertCreateVm>
</ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm>';

SELECT c.value('(Characters/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Characters
    , c.value('(TimeLeaveId/text())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS TimeLeaveId
    , c.value('(TimeMissionId/text())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS TimeMissionId
FROM @TimeConvert.nodes('/ArrayOfTimeConvertCreateVm/TimeConvertCreateVm') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Characters |             TimeLeaveId              |            TimeMissionId             |
+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|         02 | EC7C864B-7EBC-4D58-A94D-EB923FD20663 | NULL                                 |
|         05 | NULL                                 | F03BB792-5A17-4467-B097-0BD819884FC1 |
+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you dear Yitzhak ❤❤❤

This is correct but I don't know how to replace it in the main procedure ...!

Comment: Also, please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0